# Is there any difference Shallow copy and deep copy in Run time and Performance?

Tags: python

```
l = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

d = deepcopy(l)
s = copy(l)

p[0][0] = 1
s[0][0] = 1

print(l)
```

Here, the outputs are same,but my question is there is any difference between Shallow copy and deep copy in Run time and Performance ?

Comment: By definition the deepcopy should be slower in the worst scenario. But you could assert that on your own with a benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%timeit` on my laptop gives 13.4us for `deepcopy` vs. 594 ns for `copy`, so it takes about 23x longer.

This seems reasonable. The `copy` only has to copy one 2-element list; the `deepcopy` has to copy one 2-element list and two 3-element lists, and it's also got some extra overhead from the recursion. If the lists were a lot longer, but the nesting not a lot deeper, I'd expect the difference to get smaller, but still, it will always be substantial.

[Laurent LAPORTE's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704638/908494) `[list(i) for i in l]` takes 2.01us on my laptop—only 3x as slow as a `copy` instead of 23x. Of course it only has a fixed depth (2, in the specific case of his answer) rather than unlimited, but in this case, we've got a fixed-depth list, and that's not too unusual.

But performance will rarely be a good reason to choose one over the other. That assignment to the shallow copy's `s[0][0] = 1` is going to change the original list's `l[0][0]` to 1 as well. If you want that, use `copy` (or, more simply in this case, just `list`). If you don't, use `deepcopy`. And if you want exactly a specific depth, use a specific depth. (Getting the answer you need is always better than getting the wrong answer fast.)

Comment: Nice answer. Just for readability I'd simplify the last explanation to something like "The line `s[0][0] = 1` will modify the index [0][0] of the copied array" since `l` and `1` is giving a hard time to read.

Comment: @Frederik.L The problem is, the OP used these names (and he called his deep copy `p`, which… fortunately I didn't have to mention that one), and I don't want to confuse him. But I tried to rewrite it so it's clear I'm talking about the original list. Did that help?

Comment: Yes absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

deepcopy is really slow but it does the job.

For your simple case I would use a comprehension list:

```
c = [list(i) for i in l]
```

Which is really fast and pythonic.

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works for static depth. If the list were three deep instead of two, you'd need to change the comprehension to `[[list(j) for i in l for j in i]`. I think "for your simple case" implies that well enough for most readers, but maybe not for everyone.